# Importing Excel file into ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, excel

I am importing Excel sheets into ArcGIS for map-making purposes. I have one column that is not recognized. I cannot figure out what is wrong with it, I have deleted it and remade it, checked the format of the column itself and nothing is different. I know this is probably not the best explanation, but I have attached an image which will hopefully elude to what I am trying to do. The column to the right Polgray is an example of a working column, and the column to the left McElmo is an example of a column that is not working. I am 100% stumped. I have done over 100 of these now with no problems except for these two Excel sheets. I cannot find anything different, nor can I find a reason for this error. ArcGIS acts like the column to the left does not exist.

[image: Example of the error]

Comment: Do you mean column and not row? Rows are above/below columns are left/right. What is the name of the column? There are SQL reserved words you should avoid. If you have Microsoft Access try importing your Excel sheet into a new personal geodatabase.. Excel has weak typing which can be made strong by importing into a MDB, this fixes or highlights a lot of problems with Excel data.

Comment: Yeah the column sorry so its the highlighted column that is not working. I am going to try the access fix. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What is the name of the column? Does it have leading and/or trailing spaces? Punctuation characters like #$%?

Comment: I agree, check the column names. You could also try saving the excel file as .csv and import the csv instead. It sometimes work